# Ruby <, <=, >, >= value comparison code

Tags: ruby, user-input

The intent is to display message based on age.

```
puts "Age, please"

value = gets.chomp
if value < 21
  puts "Here you cannot to buy alchohol"
end

puts "You can buy all the alchohol you want"
```

What is the missing part in this code?

Answer (score 1):

if you get `value` by `gets`, `value` is String.

Use `value.to_i`

```
puts "Age, please"

value = gets
value = Integer(value) rescue 0

if value < 21
  puts "Here you cannot to buy alchohol"  
else
  puts "You can buy all the alchohol you want"
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Kimshin. he only problem is that for values < 21, this code displays both ""Here you cannot...." and "Buy all you..." outputs. It is supposed to display only one value

Comment: You need to put the second `puts` into the `if` statement as a an `else` branch.

Comment: @Koda We are not supposed to read your mind.

Comment: `gets.chomp` doesn't get the string value, `gets` does.

Comment: Your string is different from the OP's output string (it is partially syntactically correct English, where the original was not).

Comment: “Get off my page”—this page is by no means yours. @sawa answered many questions and helped many people. I downvoted the question, since it is silly, not well-stated and violates SO rules. Plus, I marked the comment as offensive.

Comment: Thank you for comments! My answer was bad. I've edited it.